# Node.js example gives 2 responses?

Tags: node.js

I have made an example script from [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) website main page like so:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
   console.log("We are connected");
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Any ideas why [each time I connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlI8T.png) to 127.0.0.1:1337 (via chromium) I get **2** responses saying "We are connected"??

Comment: Browser is sending favicon request also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two requests by the browser. One for url `/` and another for `/favicon.ico`. Try to output the request url.

```
console.log(req.url);
```